# React navigation breaks when accessing nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

As above, example of my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-mendeleev-ru5vt

The problem I'm having is when I navigate to a single project, it breaks the main navigation. The base URL seems to always go from projects once I hit a single project.

Hope fully the example above can explain the issue a little more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Links` are missing slashes, just add them. Otherwise you end up with broken paths like `/projects/tasks` by navigating to a single project.

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-mclaren-toxdb?file=/src/App.js